# Vendoring part of my repository in someone else's project

Tags: version-control, git, repository

I have a repository for a project that contains both an executable and a library.

```
My repo
|->src
   |->my-exe
   |->my-lib
```

I am now working with a company that wants to use my library in their project as well. They want to vendor (i.e., make a one-time copy of) a subset of my repository in their repository.

```
Their repo
|->src
   |->their-exe
|->vendor
   |->src
      |->my-lib
```

They won't use a submodule or clone my repository during build time. They want a separate copy of my code. I will likely be the one managing both sets of source code.

My questions is: Is there a clean way to automatically keep the two sets of code in sync so that I can manage any future changes from a single repository?

Comment: Isn't this *their* problem, not yours?

Comment: Like I said, I will likely be the one managing both sets of source code. They are hiring me to maintain my code in their repo. I'm looking for the most efficient/smallest headache approach to managing both repos.

Comment: If it's a one-time copy, why do you need to maintain anything? Is one repo just a subtree of the other? Is the executable built from the same source? Etc.

Comment: Sorry, I used "one-time" to indicate that it was not a synced copy, not that it won't be changing and need a new copy down the road as I make changes to the library. I edited the trees to help clarify the relationship: Only a subset of my repo is a subtree of their repo. Both `my-exe` and `their-exe` link to the library created from `my-lib`.

Comment: Your project should have separate repos for your library and your executable.  Their project should fork your library repo and have a separate repo for their executable.

Comment: @Kevin Krumwiede I can separate my project into separate repos, but I have no control over their project structure. I've made the argument that they should fork my repo, but they aren't having it. They want direct control over their dependencies.

Comment: Forking *would* give them direct control over their dependencies.  Maybe they don't understand that.

Comment: More so than relying on you to keep maintaining whatever structure they need. That's not the best thing for *either* party.

Comment: What language is this for? Some languages handle this better than others. Golang, while it's frustrating for dependencies in general, solves this problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution might be the git `subtree` command. In the companies repo: First add your repository (or alternatively a local fork) as remote (not strictly necessary, but simplifies stuff a bit)

```
git remote add lib https://myurl
```

Then check out your code with an appropriate prefix:

```
git subtree add --prefix vendor/src/my-lib lib master
```

*(You can also use `--squash` if you don't want all those commits in the company repo)*

To update just fetch and pull:

```
git fetch lib master
git subtree pull --prefix vendor/src/my-lib lib master
```

You can also commit local changes and push them back to your repo:

```
git subtree push --prefix vendor/src/my-lib lib master
```

Users of the company repo don't need to bother with all of this, they can work with the repo in the usual ways.

A (much more detailed) description of the above can also be found in this [Atlassian blog entry](https://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/).

Answer (score 0):

> They won't use a submodule or clone my repository during build time.

I think this is an XY problem.  They and/or you do not seem to understand what a fork is or how to maintain it.  It would not be cloned *during build time*.  It would be cloned once when the project is set up, and remain completely under their control just like the rest of their project.  They could keep the original version forever, or update it from your upstream version as they see fit.

Comment: They want a solution that can be built entirely with git, cmake, and a compiler such that the entire project can be built with `git clone their-repo-url; cmake .; make;`. So a fork alone doesn't solve that problem unless it is cloned and referenced by cmake. Regardless, a fork is not an acceptable solution. I'm not looking for what's wrong with their logic, but how to work with it regardless of how dumb it may seem.